# Why do SpringJDBCTemplate Issues occur when I am trying to connect to Multiple DBs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

Here is my Error, I'm going to connect multiple mysql DB's. For one DB it is works perfectly. Then I tried for 2 DB's, but I'm getting an error.Please help me to sort out this issue.
Seems my changes for multiple DB is wrong :-\

**ERROR**

```
    ec 10, 2015 10:23:06 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Found 4 annotated classes in package [net.codejava.spring]
Dec 10, 2015 10:23:07 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO net.codejava.spring.controller.HomeController.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO net.codejava.spring.controller.HomeController.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)

Dec 10, 2015 10:23:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO net.codejava.spring.controller.HomeController.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO net.codejava.spring.controller.HomeController.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)

Dec 10, 2015 10:23:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /SpringMvcJdbcTemplate threw load() exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
```

Here is my Controller Class

@Controller
public class HomeController {

```
@Autowired
private ContactDAO contactDAO;

@Autowired
private ContactDAO2 contactDAO2;

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
    List<Contact> listContact = contactDAO.list();
    model.addObject("listContact", listContact);
    model.setViewName("home");

    return model;
}
```

Here is my DAO Class#01

```
public interface ContactDAO {

    public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact);
```

Here is my DAO Class#02

```
public interface ContactDAO2 {

    public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact);
```

Here is my DAOImpl Class

```
public class ContactDAO2Impl implements ContactDAO2 {

    @Autowired 
    @Qualifier("jdbcItems") 
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public ContactDAO2Impl(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact) {
        if (contact.getId() > 0) {
            // update
            String sql = "UPDATE contact SET name=?, email=?, address=?, "
                        + "telephone=? WHERE contact_id=?";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql, contact.getName(), contact.getEmail(),
                    contact.getAddress(), contact.getTelephone(), contact.getId());
        }
```

Here is my another DAOImpl class

```
public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDAO {

    @Autowired 
    @Qualifier("jdbcUsers") 
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public ContactDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact) {
        if (contact.getId() > 0) {
            // update
            String sql = "UPDATE contact SET name=?, email=?, address=?, "
                        + "telephone=? WHERE contact_id=?";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql, contact.getName(), contact.getEmail(),
                    contact.getAddress(), contact.getTelephone(), contact.getId());
        }
```

Below shows my config classes
**config#01**

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages="net.codejava.spring")
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        }


    }
```

**config#02**

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseItemsConfig {

    @Bean(name = "jdbcItems")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dsItems) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsItems);
    }

    @Bean(name = "dsItems")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("321");
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

**config#03**

```
    @Configuration
public class DatabaseUsersConfig {


    @Bean(name = "jdbcUsers") 
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dsUsers) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsUsers);
    }

    @Bean(name = "dsUsers") 
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("321");
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

whole project uploaded with source Code

[Click here to see & get my whole project code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-EtnZm4mdxad2QyQjJKQ0llamc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your `jdbcUsers` bean is a `DataSource`, not a `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: Dear Kayaman.. I changed it .But the error is same

Comment: Well, read the rest of the stacktrace to find the root cause (you're only showing a part of it, which doesn't contain the actual error). Also edit your code to show how you changed it.

Comment: I edited the code as per u say & swap bean names in DatabaseItemsConfig class

Comment: Well why in the world would you do that? The bean names are wrong in `DatabaseUsersConfig` class. No wonder your code isn't working.

Comment: i double checked it Dear Kayaman.seems no error in those config classes now.edited code edited above too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97544/discussion-between-priyanka-and-kayaman).

Comment: Stop calling me "Dear", you're not my aunt. Also pay attention to your writing, because even if you wrote the code correctly, you're talking about `DatabaseItemsConfig` in your previous comment.

Comment: sorry about my poor english.I'm Sinhalese.thats why :-(
all config classes now changed as per u say & recheck.seems its correct now.can u please go through my code & point the exact line.

Comment: Are you missing the `@Component` annotations for your `ContactDAO` classes, or did you just leave them out of your posting? It's not very easy to help you, when I can't trust that you're posting the correct things.

Comment: u mean in DAO interface or DAOImpl Classes.?

Comment: Whichever, neither of them has it.

Comment: Have you googled for the error to understand what it is telling you? This question have been asked here a number of times too: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22at+least+1+bean+which+qualifies+as+autowire%22

Comment: i'm googling now.i not added @component annotation.but its worked for one db :-\

Comment: please refer the attached total source code

Answer (score 1):

You have many problems in the wiring .. to fix that :

Remove ( from ContactDAOImpl )

```
 @Autowired 
 @Qualifier("jdbcUsers")
```

And ( from ContactDAO2Impl )

```
 @Autowired 
 @Qualifier("jdbcItems")
```

And

```
 @Bean(name = "jdbcItems")
 public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dsItems) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dsItems);
 }
```

And

```
 @Bean(name = "jdbcUsers") 
 public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dsUsers) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dsUsers);
 }
```

Then replace

```
 public ContactDAO2Impl(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
 }
```

By

```
 public ContactDAO2Impl(@Qualifier("dsItems") DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
 }
```

And replace

```
 public ContactDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
 }
```

By

```
 public ContactDAOImpl(@Qualifier("dsUsers") DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
 }
```

Comment: i tried ur way but error is same.shall i upload all code to host.?

Comment: i juste  have made some modifications .... i made mistakes .. try to fix it again

Comment: ok i'll check it now and try to test after applying.uploaded my source  coded too :-)

Comment: ur above modification applied.but error is same.please fix that directly and send me .tnx a lot

Comment: you can download the fixed code

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_ufI5GwtmgVeENpYk1EQWhmcmM